# Couchbase: Setting up a local Dev Environment

Tags: php, apache, windows-7, couchbase

Over the past few days i've been trying to set up a dev environment for couchbase for a project of mine. Basically im trying to follow along with example in the following link:

http://www.couchbase.com/communities/php/getting-started

I've managed to install the PHP libraries no problem the problem is no matter what i try i cant seem to make the server run. The service doesnt even boot straight after install (as it apparently should). If i try to start it manually i get the following error:

http://puu.sh/bk6KG.png

Anyone have any idea what the problem is?

Comment: A better dev environment might be running linux on a virtualbox and installing Couchbase there. Unless you're stuck with an MS server it will get your closer to actual deployment environment.

Comment: I'm well aware of the benefits of running linux instead of windows (i've been doing this a long time) but i dont need suggestions on how to change the environment to suit the install, i need answers on how to make the install work...



The issue is simple, it was supposedly a 1 click install according to every tutorial ive watched and read, so why is it not working the way it should?

Comment: It will only be a single master node setup for now, and if i wanted a linux environment i would just use vagrant, but i dont want to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very strange, I have recently launched couchbase server on two Windows 7 systems and clustered them. It was working "out of the box".
In you case, I recommend you some standard actions:

1. Double click the CouchbaseServer service
2. Dependencies tab
3. Check services list under label: "This service depends on the following system components"
4. Make sure, that all services from list are started

Hope this helps you

Comment: Thank you very much for pointing me in the right direction.

It turns out that part of the SMB protocol on the system was corrupted. Since the machine in question doesnt file share with any linux based resources i didn't notice.

All i had to do was troubleshoot that then restart the "workstation" service that governs it and presto the 1068 Error msg disappeared.